# Memory leak NSAutoreleasePool

Tags: memory-leaks, uiimage, nsdata, instruments, nsautoreleasepool

With instruments i got a memory leak on this piece of code and i don't understand why!

```
-(void)goToThisUrl:(id) targetUrl
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    if (someCondition) {
        // Doing some stuff here
    }
    // Instruments show memory leak on data
    else {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: targetUrl]];
        myTargetImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        // When releasing data(because data retainCount = 2), i got:
        // Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller
        //[data release];
    }   
    [pool release];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are doing this for a detached thread, right?

Comment: Yes, this is why i allocate an NSAutoreleasePool to this method :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no leak in the above. There *may* be one or more leaks in the parts you've deleted and replaced with "someCondition" and "Doing some stuff here," but no one here can help with that unless you post the **complete** code that you're really testing with Instruments.

Also: "// When releasing data(because data retainCount = 2) ..." Stop. Right. There. Ignore retainCount. You release an object because you've created it using a method that implies ownership, or because you've retained it. You **NEVER** release an object just because its retainCount has a value you didn't expect or don't understand. Read Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't allocate a UIImage in a second thread. Uses of UIKit need to be on the main thread. I assume what you wanted to do by creating another thread was to invoke dataWithContentsOfURL without blocking the main thread. But, this is not the right approach. Instead, use a NSURLConnection with an async callback that gets invoked when the download is done. Apple already provides a built-in "download" thread that NSURLConnection uses behind the scenes. So, your approach of creating another thread to download is pointless.