# Memory leak NSAutoreleasePool

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsthread, nsautoreleasepool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Memory leak NSAutoreleasePool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763935/memory-leak-nsautoreleasepool)

Hello,

can someone tell me how to fix this leak(instruments show a leak in this method) :

```
-(void)goToThisUrl:(id) targetUrl
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    if (someCondition) {
        // Doing some stuff here
    }
    // Instruments show memory leak on data
    else {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: targetUrl]];
        myTargetImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        // When releasing data(because data retainCount = 2), i got:
        // Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller
        //[data release];
    }   
    [pool release];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's no leak in the above to fix. Perhaps it's in the code you replaced with "Doing some stuff here"?

Comment: Also: "// When releasing data(because data retainCount = 2) ..." Stop. Right. There. Ignore retainCount. You release an object because you've created it using a method that implies ownership, or because you've retained it. You **NEVER** release an object just because its retainCount has a value you didn't expect or don't understand. Read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html for details.

Comment: @Anomie Good catch. @iPadNewProgrammer Are you vince?

Comment: Yes i'm Vince but i was not a registrated user and i lost always my posts and points so i decide to make an account.

Comment: I confirm that Instriments show me a memory leak in this piece of code.

Comment: @iPadNewProgrammer Consider [merging your accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste).

Comment: @Bavarious I'm a registred user now, so it's OK.

Comment: The above doesn't even compile. You replaced the contents of the if() with "someCondition." You deleted code and replaced it with "Doing some stuff here." Please post the code that you're **really** testing with Instruments and stop wasting our time.

Comment: @Sherm Pendley Really SORRY for waisting your precious time, you're not forced to ask my question nor to waist your time reading it! "Civility costs nothing and buys everything"

Comment: You're right - I don't have to answer your question. And if that's how you're going to respond to me when I'm trying to help, I should just go answer someone who knows how to say "thank you." Because I'm such a nice guy though, I'll give you one last chance - are you here to argue, or to get help? If you're here to get help, you need to post your real code, because the leak Instruments is referring to is **not** in the part you posted.

Comment: @Sherm Pendley thankyou anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `data` is already an autoreleased piece of memory, having been created by an NSData convenience function. If you did not alloc it (by calling `alloc`) then you don't have to release it. So, you need not call `[data release]` and there is no leak here. You can run this with Intruments and the Leaks tool to verify, of course.

Comment: I run it as a method of a detached  NSThread and i have a memory leak with it!

Comment: Hmm.. Well, all I can say is: you're using two convenience methods (of NSData and of UIImage) that create objects for you AND manage that memory. So, there is little you can do about it, if it's any of those objects that are leaking. Try doing a Build and Analyze and see what, if anything, is reported about memory leaks in that part of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will try to change my code and see if still got this leak.